# Initializing an array of UDT in VB6

Tags: vb6, initialization, user-defined-types

I have declared an UDT and I need to initialise an array with specific records of the UDT, how would I do it at the module level.

Here is what I've tried

```
Public Type MyType
    id     As Integer
    name   As String
    values As Double
End Type

private MY_TYPES(1) As MyType
My_TYPES(0) = newMyType(1, "Item 1", 15.9)
My_TYPES(1) = newMyType(2, "Item 2", 30.2)

Private Function newMyType(byval id as Integer, byval name as String, _ 
                           byval v as Double) As MyType
    Dim t As MyType
    t.id = id
    t.name = name
    t.value = v
    newMyType = t
End Function
```

The error I get is `Invalid outside procedure`

As you can see it I try to reproduce what would be static initialization of a java `Collection` like a `List` or  `Set`

I would like to expose the collection as constant, how could I achive this?

Comment: The two lines where you assign to the My_TYPES array cannot be written outside of a procedure. They must be inside a function/sub/property like your newMyType function.

Answer (score 3):

you have to place the following 2 lines in a sub, and then call the sub to init the udt

```
My_TYPES(0) = newMyType(1, "Item 1", 15.9)
My_TYPES(1) = newMyType(2, "Item 2", 30.2)
```

or you can can place these 2 lines in the working sub inside an if..then with a module level init boolean

Comment: +1. If your module is a class, you can put the lines in class_initialize so that they are run automatically. You will need to manage the initialise yourself if they are in a BAS module